# How many is the minimum number of players required to play multiplayer?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I think it's four players readied, but in the Casual Rescue lobby that I'm in, the timer didn't start until a fifth player joined and they didn't have to ready up.

Does it change depending on the game mode? And does it matter if players ready up or not?